# copy (multiple) files only if filesize is smaller

Tags: copy, compare, batch-processing, filesize

I'm trying to make my image reference library take up less space. I know how to make Photoshop batch save directories of images with a particular amount of compression. **BUT** some of my images were originally save with more compression than what I would have done.

So I wind up with two directories of images, some of the newer files have a larger filesize, some smaller, and some the same. I want to copy over the new images into the old directory, **excluding** any files that have a larger filesize (or the same, though these probably aren't numerous enough for me to care about the extra time to process them).

I obviously don't want to sit there and parse through each file, but other than that I'm not picky about how it gets tackled.

running Windows 10, btw.

Comment: I've looked through xcopy, xxcopy, robocopy, terracopy, and beyond compare. Most allow filtering if filesize is different, but don't have a flag for smaller. One of them (I forget which program) would let me flag files of a larger filesize, but wouldn't let me invert that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have similar situations. Instead of Photoshop, I use FFmpeg (using its qscale option) to batch re-encode multiple images into a subfolder then use XXCOPY to overwrite only the larger original source images. In fact I ended up creating my BATCH file which let FFmpeg do the batch e-encoding (using its "best" qscale setting), then let ExifTool batch copy the metadata to the newly encoded images, then let XXCOPY copy only the smaller newly created images. All automated, with the "new" folder and its leftover newly created but larger-sized images deleted too. Thus I save considerable disk space, as I have many images categorized/grouped in many different folders. But you should make a test run first or back up your images. I hope this works for you.

Here is my XXCOPY command line:
**xxcopy "C:\SOURCE" "C:\DESTINATION" /s /bzs /y**

The original post/forum where I learned this from is:

**overwrite only files wich are smaller**
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/Agooyf23kFw

Just to add, XXCOPY can also do it if the larger file size is wanted instead which I think is **/BZL**. I think it's also mentioned in that original post/forum.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I think /BZL is only larger files, as well. I'll have to look into FFmpeg, too. XNView is also good for batching images.